# Authenticate to autodesk

Tags: java, autodesk-forge

We are developing a Java application that is supposed to show models from users store. 
initially, I'm trying to allow users to login using their autodesk account, and check if they are entitled to access my app.

I couldn't find any good example to show how it is done, I just want to confirm that what I will be doing is the recommended thing or if there is better options.

First, on app start, I will show an embedded webbrowser that will open 
"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=XXX&scope=XXX"

the app will get the url from our server (so not saved locally) and the call back is pointing to an api on our server. then as user login and consent, will get the code from the url, close the login dialog and continue to get the bearer token using plain rest apis to /authentication/v1/gettoken.

As I said, not 100% sure if this is approved way or not or even if it is doable or not. so thought to check before we implement it.

After that I will just use rest apis to browse and get the model. 
any thoughts or complains ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Rest assured that the workflow being proposed here is actually orthodoxical and well “approved” by our official tutorials:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/
- http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/oauth/3legged/
- Unfortunaly the code sample for that bit is in node and we are still working on a Java equilvalent

Some of our endpoints require 3-legged oauth to access personal data - see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-me-GET/) for an example and you can always refer to the `authentication context` section of each endpoint for the oauth flow required.